# Configuring Hibernate XML with P-Namespace

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, spring

I want to rewrite my sessionFactory bean using the p-namespace. I understand how to reference general objects, but I've never dealt with lists, props, etc. How would I go about writing , and so on?

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>/com/mysite/domain/Object.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
           <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> 
        </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

This is the code I have so far in p-namespace:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
    p:mappingResources-list="/com/mysite/domain/Object.hbm.xml" 
    p:hibernateProperties-props=""/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this directly . You could use util:map though. Try

```
    <util:map id="hibernateConfig" >
        <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <!-- Other properties -->
    </util:map>

   <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
  p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
  p:mappingResources-list="/com/mysite/domain/Object.hbm.xml" 
  p:hibernateProperties-ref ="hibernateConfig"/>
```

Check [This](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-p-namespace) for complete help on p:namespace

Comment: As for now, using utils is beyond me. But this makes me wonder - could the use of p-namespace further complicate things in terms of code-readability?

Comment: It depends on the users . I am comfortable using the property option and depend on Auto detecting components and Autowiring whenever I can . Users following the older Spring approach may find the annotations intriguing but they generally get over it . So I feel , in case of the p:namespace also , people will get used to the coding style in time .

Comment: What irks me is that when I entered in the util:map part of the code into my application.xml, the IDE detected an error. Looking up the reference that you cited doesn't help me *yet*, because I don't know enough xml. But I suppose I'd definitely have to hit the XML tutorial in W3Schools.

Comment: That would be properly because you haven't defined the namespace and schema location . You would have to have something similar to the ove used [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html) .<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">